# Passing int by reference in c?

Tags: c

```
void test(void *a)
{
    int *h = a;  //error
}
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{
    int z = 13;

    test(&z);

    return 0;
}
```

If I want to keep the void *a for test function, how can I get error line working?

Comment: That is perfectly valid C code. My guess is that you are using a C++ compiler in which case you would need to explicitly cast `a` to an `int *` in your `test` function.

Comment: What was the error, all I get is a warning (with `-Wall`) of *unused variable 'h'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to compile and run the following with `gcc` without warning or error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void *a)
{
        int *h = a;
        printf("test: %d\n", *h);
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
        int z = 13;
        test(&z);
        return 0;
}
```

The only conceivable reason you would be getting an error on the line you indicated is that you are using a C++ compiler (`g++` maybe?). If I try that I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’
```

If you need to use a C++ compiler, you need to explicitly cast `a` to an `int *`:

```
int *h = (int *) a;
```

That one change allows this code to compile with `g++` as well.

Comment: Same thing with MSVC - adding the line dereferencing `*h` generates no warning or error.